# FFMPEG - Merge Video-A with audio of of Video-B in a single command?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I would like to use the video of `video A`, and put the audio of `video B` on top. How would I do this with ffmpeg in the command line? I have found tutorials to do this with extracting the audio first to a wav file, but I **was wondering whether it's possible to do this in a single command?** and **without transcoding** everything again?

edit: both files are `.mp4` files and both contain video & audio. both files are of equal length.

Comment: Does A have audio and do you wish to mix it with B's ?

Comment: I'm sorry I should've been more clear! A does have audio and I want to get rid of it, only keeping the video. B does have video and I want to get rid of it, only keeping the audio.

Comment: Length of output i.e. what if B's audio is longer?

Comment: thats not a worry, in my case they will always be of equal length.

Answer (score 3):

Basic command form is

```
ffmpeg -i videoA -i videoB -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy videoAaudioB.mp4
```

Basic requirement is that A's video and B's audio should be compatible with file format of the output.